# Is it possible to change how json data is parsed depending on the value of a certain string?

Tags: jquery, json

currently im using jQuery to parse a JSON object and then list of the values in a table. In the table i have hardcoded the beginning of the URL and then I append a value to end of it. The problem that i have is that the value of a specific string changes, and I would need that hardcoded URL to change based the value of the string.

Here is an example of the string:

```
[
    {
        "Search Engine":"Google",
        "Keywords":"ac ardmore ok",
        "Website":"http:\/\/www.websitename.com",
        "Position":"2",
        "Previous":"2",
        "Change":"-",
        "Page":"1",
        "Best":"1",
        "id":0
    },{
        "Search Engine":"Yahoo",
        "Keywords":"ac davis ok",
        "Website":"http:\/\/www.websitename.com",
        "Position":"1",
        "Previous":"1",
        "Change":"-",
        "Page":"1",
        "Best":"1",
        "id":1
    },{
        "Search Engine":"Bing",
        "Keywords":"ac davis ok",
        "Website":"http:\/\/www.websitename.com",
        "Position":"1",
        "Previous":"1",
        "Change":"-",
        "Page":"1",
        "Best":"1",
        "id":2
    },{
        "Search Engine":"Google Mobile",
        "Keywords":"ac davis ok",
        "Website":"http:\/\/www.websitename.com",
        "Position":"1",
        "Previous":"1",
        "Change":"-",
        "Page":"1",
        "Best":"1",
        "id":3
    }
]
```

The Search Engine string is the one is question, and as you can see the value can be Google, Yahoo, Bing, or Google Mobile. Below you will see my current code for parsing the data:

```
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: KeywordRank,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            var keywordHTML = '';
            jQuery.each(response, function (i, item) {
                keywordHTML += '<tr><td class="tg-yw4l">' + item['Search Engine'] + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l"><a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=' + item.Keywords + '" target="_blank">' + item.Keywords + '</a></td><td class="tg-yw4l"><a href="' + item.Website + '" target="_blank">' + item.Website + '</a></td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + item.Position + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + item.Previous + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l change">' + item.Change + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + item.Page + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + item.Best + '</td></tr>';
            });
            jQuery('#keyword_ranking').append(keywordHTML);
        }
    });
```

As you can see the hardcoded URL is as follows:

```
<td class="tg-yw4l"><a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=' + item.Keywords + '" target="_blank">' + item.Keywords + '</a></td>
```

Is it possible to change that hardcoded URL to a Yahoo search string if the value is Yahoo, a Bing search string if the value is Bing, and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running *item['Search Engine']* through a switch statement you can modify the search engine url accordingly.

```
var engineUrl;
switch (item['Search Engine']) {
   case "Google":
   case "Google Mobile":
        engineUrl = "https://www.google.com/search?q=";
      break;
   case "Bing":
      engineUrl = "https://www.bing.com/search?q=";
      break;
   case "Yahoo":
      engineUrl = "https://search.yahoo.com/search?p=";
      break;
   default:
       engineUrl = "https://www.google.com/search?q=";
}
```

I created a working example for you here: https://jsfiddle.net/g3k7320p/1/

Comment: That was perfect, didnt even think about using switch on this one!